# The extension of a connected, simply-connected Lie group by $\mathbb{Z}$ is trivial.

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, group-cohomology, group-extensions

I am reading [a paper by Calvin Moore](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1964-113-01/S0002-9947-1964-0171880-5/S0002-9947-1964-0171880-5.pdf) on group extensions. On page 54, there is a statement saying that when a Lie group is connected and simply-connected, the the extension of a connected, simply-connected Lie group by $\mathbb{Z}$ is trivial. He said it is easy to see this. However, it is not obvious to me. Is there any reason for that?  I am trying not to use the technique of introducing the classifying space since at that time it had not been invented.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $G$ is a simply connected topological group, $D$ is a discrete group, and we have an extension of topological groups $1\to D \to H \stackrel{p}\to G\to 1$.  Then $p$ is a covering map.  Explicitly, if $U$ is a neighborhood of $1$ in $H$ which contains no other points of $D$ and $V$ is a neighborhood of $1$ such that $VV^{-1}\subseteq U$, then the cosets of $V$ by elements of $D$ are disjoint (if $aV\cap bV\neq \emptyset$ for $a,b\in D$ then we get that $b^{-1}a$ is equal to an element of $VV^{-1}\subseteq U$ so $a=b$).  It follows that $p(V)$ is a neighborhood of $1$ in $G$ which is evenly covered by $p$, and translates of $p(V)$ show that every point of $G$ has an evenly covered neighborhood.

Since $G$ is simply connected, this covering map must be trivial and we have $H\cong G\times D$ (this is an isomorphism of spaces over $G$, but not yet of topological groups).  We can then identify $G$ with the connected component of the identity in $H$.  Since $D$ is normal in $H$, $G$ acts on it by conjugation, but this action must be trivial since $G$ is connected.  So, every element of $G$ commutes with every element of $D$, and we see that $H\cong G\times D$ as a topological group and our extension is trivial.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have some questions. Could you help me understand this better? (1) Is it obvious why $p$ has to be a covering map? (2) what do you mean by $VV^{-1}$?

Comment: I proved that $p$ is a covering map, since translates of $p(V)$ are evenly covered by $p$ and form an open cover of $G$.  $VV^{-1}$ just means $\{vw^{-1}:v,w\in V\}$.

Comment: The action of $G$ on $D$ is trivial probably because there is no homomorphism from $G$ to $Aut(D)$.

Comment: This is just because $G$ is connected and $D$ is discrete.  The image of each element of $D$ under the action of $G$ must be a connected subset of $D$, so it can only be a single point.